# Raspberry Pi relay on GPIO does not toggle, but does on +3V power

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, switching

I am trying to toggle an [SRD-03VDC-SL-C](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fsc01.alicdn.com%2Fkf%2FHTB12_3AMVXXXXbTaXXXq6xXFXXXQ.jpg_350x350.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) (3V rated) relay with a Raspberry Pi GPIO.

When I put a wire to the Raspberry Pi 2B ground pin and the other to a 3.3V power pin the relay works (it clicks). I measured 3.28V with my multimeter.

Now, as the relay is confirmed to be working I want to toggle it via software by switching a GPIO pin. I confirmed that the GPIO switching is working with my multimeter: It shows 3.28 V when high and 0 V when low.

But when I connect the wire with the GPIO in high state it does not toggle the relay. How is this possible when both pins have the same voltage and how can I fix this?

Experimenting with the Raspberry I also observed the situation that I could set the voltage to 0 but disconnecting then made a difference. I would assume that in this case disconnecting would not make a difference.

Comment: A I/O pin cannot deliver the amount of current required to drive a relay coil (trying to do so can damage the device). Buffer the signal with a transistor.

Comment: Are you using a bare relay or a relay module?

Comment: Currently using a bare relay.

Comment: Measure the GPIO output *while the relay is connected* and add that to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GPIO pin cannot provide enough current to a relay directly. Use the GPIO pin to drive a transistor, and use the transistor to drive the relay.

Comment: Thank you. This explains it. I will try that and if it works, accept your answer.